# Смысл this в C++ / self в Python

Tags: c++, python, классы

В чем суть `self` в ООП языка Python и `this` в C++ (лучше в примерах)?

Comment: Это ссылка (адрес, указатель) на текущий экземпляр объекта

Answer (score 11):

Верно подмечено, что эти понятия имеют одну и ту же роль в ООП, объектно-ориентированном программировании: это отсылка объекта к самому себе. Она позволяет:

1. Обращаться к собственным полям (т.е, переменным) и методам;
2. Передавать объекту самого себя в другие функции и объекты.

**Python** и **C++** отличаются тем, что первая часть в C++ (ещё в Java, C# и Objective-C) реализована автоматически, нам не обязательно постоянно прописывать **`self`** или **`this`**. Однако это порождает либо путаницу между переменными объекта и локальными, либо постоянное использование нижнего подчёркивания в названии переменных, что, на мой взгляд, не сильно лучше ссылки на объект. Наоборот, в Питоне (и, например, JavaScript'e) необходимо всегда явно указывать, если обращение идёт к полю текущего объекта.

Рассмотрим оба варианта использования.

### 1) Для обращения к своим полям

Возьмём класс `прямоугольник`, у него есть две переменные с длинами сторон: `a` и `b`, нам нужен метод для вычисления площади – а для этого нужно обращаться из метода к полям объекта. Код на Python:

```py
class Rect:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        # по наличию или отсутствию self различаются
        # локальные переменные и поля объекта
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    # self явно присутствует в аргументах методов
    def area(self):
        return self.a * self.b
```

В языке C++ для этого есть разные способы. Вариант А:

```cpp
class Rect {
    private:
        int _a, _b;

    public:
        Rect(int a, int b) {
            // нижнее подчёркивание используется для того, чтобы
            // различать аргументы/локальные переменные
            // и поля объекта
            _a = a;
            _b = b;
        }

        int area() {
            // this нет ни в аргументах метода,
            // ни в обращении к полям объекта
            return _a * _b;
        }
}
```

C++, вариант Б:

```cpp
class Rect {
    private:
        int a, b;

    public:
        Rect(int a, int b) : a(a), b (b) {
            // такой способ инициализации полей объекта
            // позволяет избегать путаницы с аргументами
        }

        int area() {
            // также, для обращения к собственным переменным
            // можно использовать this 
            return this->a * this->b;
        }
}
```

---

### Лирическое отступление

Обратите внимание на то, что в методах на Питоне `self` всегда указывается явно, а в C++ `this` принимает значение автоматически. И хотя конструкция применяется одна и та же `object.method(data)`, а в объявлении методов `this` не используется, на самом деле ссылка на объект присутствует как скрытый первый аргумент. Можно указать объект и явным образом, вот две эквивалентные строки C++ кода:

```cpp
my_object.push(3);

MyClass::push(&my_object, 3);

// надеюсь, Вы понимаете C++ значение символов & и *
// если нет, спешите скорее разузнать
```

Для `my_object` как экземпляра класса такого вида:

```cpp
class MyClass {
    ...

    void push(int number) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Кстати, подобным образом явно указать объект можно и в Питоне:

```py
# неявная передача объекта в первый аргумент
my_object.push(2)

# явное указание объекта как аргумента
MyClass.push(my_object, 2)
```

---

### 2) Для передачи текущего объекта

Например, у нас есть какой-нибудь объект контроллер или контейнер, и объекты нашего класса должны автоматически туда положиться или удалиться из него. Python:

```py
all = []

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        all.append(self)
```

C++:

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();
}

vector<MyClass*> all = new vector<MyClass*>();

MyClass::MyClass() {
    all.push(this);
}
```

Comment: `Rect(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {} // не надо никаких подчёркиваний`

Comment: @Qwertiy можно и так, конечно :) но конструктор ведь не единственное, где переменные объекта могут спутаться с локальными. Можно предложить более длинны, говорящие имена, можно было бы использовать префикс в виде текущего объекта – как по мне, оба варианта хороши, просто предпочитаю второй.

Comment: this->a есть же

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков конечно есть, я и не говорил обратного. Просто такое обращение к своим полям не слишком популярно в плюсах. Наверное, стоит добавить в ответ.

Comment: Но кроме конструкторов мало мест, где имена совпадают. Кстати, у объектов вообще нет переменных есть только поля.

Comment: @Qwertiy я об этом упомянул на третьей строке, просто решил не зацикливаться. Уверен, новичкам проще без слишком обширной терминологии, а более опытные разберутся.

Comment: проблемы обращения к данным с this и без него могут вылезти, например, в шаблонах. К примеру: http://rextester.com/ZIWUV34386 и тоже самое на другом компиляторе: http://rextester.com/UIJAQZ72816

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков отличный пример!