# Ключевое слово this в java

Tags: java, python

Я начал изучать java и натолкнулся на слово this но не очень понял для чего оно нужно. Но я уже знаю python и у меня возник вопрос слово this в java тоже самое, что и слово self в python ?

Comment: В целом да. Можете [почитать похожий ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/773475/198251) о сравнении `this` из C++ и `self` из Python – `this` из Плюсов очень похож на `this` из Java, только там это указатель, а в Джаве ссылка.

Answer (score 5):

В `Java` слово `this` используется в двух разных значениях.

1) Когда оно используется как переменная объектного типа, типа `this.value = 5;`, оно означает тот объект, к которому относится код, использующий `this`. Используется это для разрешения неоднозначности, когда, например, есть поле объекта и локальная переменная с одинаковыми именами, тогда просто `qq++` означает инкремент локальной переменной `qq`, а `this.qq++` означает инкремент одноименного поля объекта. Иногда может использоваться просто для повышения читабельности. Довольно часто можно встретить такое его использование в конструкторах, когда имена параметров конструктора совпадают с именами полей, такого вот типа:

```
class Person {
  private String name; // Поля объекта
  private int age;

  // Создаём объект с заданными значениями полей
  public Person(String name, int age) { // При вызове зададим начальные значения в виде параметров
    this.name = name;  // Значения этих параметров 
    this.age = age;    // присваиваются переменным объекта
  }
}
```

Понятно, что в статических методах его использовать нельзя, так как статические методы не принадлежат какому-то отдельному объекту.

2) Оно может использоваться в конструкторе в форме вызова метода, типа `this(someValue)`, и тогда оно означает вызов другого конструктора этого же класса. Используется для сокращения кода, когда двум разным конструкторам нужно выполнить одни и те же действия, напр.

```
class Person {
  private String name; // Поля объекта
  private int age;

  public Person(String name, int age) { // Создаём объект с заданными значениями полей
    this.name = name;  // Значения параметров 
    this.age = age;    // присваиваются переменным объекта
  }

  public Person() { // Создаём объект с некими дефолтными значениями 
    this("NoName", -1);  // Вызов другого конструктора
  }

}
```

В этом примере задача второго конструктора -- просто обеспечить какие-то значения полей, если их не предоставил пользователь. С этими значениями второй конструктор вызывает первый конструктор, который присваивает полученные значения соответствующим полям.

P.S. Да, ответ про C++, упомянутый в комментарии AivanF, напомнил мне еще один важный момент -- использование `this` -- это единственный способ для объекта передать себя в качестве параметра при вызове метода или вернуть себя в качестве результата выполнения метода:

```
public MyClass registeredSelf() {
  registrator.register(this); // Зарегистрируйте меня
  this.registered = true;
  return this;   
}
```