# Для чего в python нужен self?

Tags: python

Ребят, кто может нормально объяснить для чего в языке python нужен self? Уже несколько статей перечитала и все никак не могу понять. Буду крайне благодарна...

Comment: Ссылка на `этот` объект класса.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нормально объяснить может dark:

> dark‎: у котов внутри есть мурчалка
>
> dark‎: она реализована для всех котов в классе кот
>
> ‎dark‎: в объекте кот надо как то вызвать метод мурчало у класса кот
>
> ‎dark‎: как ты это сделаешь?
>
> dark‎: кот.мурчало()
>
> ‎dark‎: ежели ты вызовешь кот.мурчало(), муркнут сразу все коты на
>   свете
>
> ‎dark‎: а ежели ты вызовешь self.мурчало(), муркнет только тот кот, на
>   которого указывает self

[Ссылка](https://bash.im/quote/431716)

Answer (score 3):

Просто сам объект, от которого вызван метод.

Answer (score 1):

`self` нужен для обращения к полям экземпляра класса и вообще для обозначения экземпляра класса. Есть подробный ответ, например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/773458/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB-this-%D0%B2-c-self-%D0%B2-python) .

Answer (score 1):

```
class Dog: # 1. Создаём класс
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Имя моей собаки {self.name}'


nick_name = Dog("Rex") # 2. Создаём экземпляр класса

print(nick_name) # 3. Принтим, что мы задали для вывода в консоль
# Имя моей собаки Rex # 3.1. Вот такой должен получиться вывод в консоли

nick_name.name # 4. Запрашиваем значение атрибута "name", которое было передано при создании экземпляра класса "nick_name"
# 'Rex' # 4.1. Получаем вывод
```

Т.е. если приглядеться, то можно увидеть некую параллель между записью "self.name" (см. п. 1.) и записью "nick_name.name" (см. п. 4.).

Сам "self" – это своеобразная ссылка на будущий экземпляр класса "nick_name".

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы понять, ответьте на вопросы

```
L = len(globals())

class Foo:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__new__')  # почему выведется перед __init__, и что лежит в cls ?
        return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls)  # почему это self ?

    def __init__(self, a):  # почему в __init__ есть агрумент self, т.е. он существует до вызова ?
        self.a = a
        print('__init__')  # почему выведется после __new__ ?

    def bar(ARG):  # почему можно переименовать в ARG, а не self ?
        print(ARG.a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(len(globals()) - L, 'новых переменных')  # почему тут 2 шт., если мы создали только переменную L ?

    _self_ = type('ob', (object,), dict(a='A'))
    Foo.bar(_self_)  # 'A' - почему можно использовать не создавая объекта Foo ?

    self = Foo('B')  # первое создание объекта - почему это self ?
    self.bar()  # 'B'  # обычное использование - почему в bar() один аргумент(self), а мы не передаем его ?
    self.bar.__call__()  # 'B' - почему можно с __call__ ?

    _self_.a = 'C'
    self.bar.__func__(_self_)  # 'C' - почему можно использовать так self.bar через _self_ ?
```